# Setting PHP super globals using http in C

Tags: php, c, http, get, http-post

Ok I know that a login Form normally has a button, and the form is usually registered to an action script that will get called whenever a user clicks on the submit button. On form submission PHP globals $POST['Xxx'] and GET['XXX'] get set according to the values in the form input.

What i want to do is , i want to have a PHP script say server.php with internal variable $serverName, 
Now i want to set this variable ( $serverName ) through a url unlike with the form data that gets picked up by the php action script whenever a user clicks on submit. I will have a C program that sends an http url request to the server with variable data. i.e. [url]www.mysite.com/server.php?serverName=awesomeServer[/url] , at this point the server.php script should know that its internal variable $serverName now equals "awesomeServer" then process some custom mysql transactions.

The question is how do i set the variable $servername to $serverName="awesomeServer" through an http request url?

Comment: You *really* don't want to do this - there's a good reason that [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) was removed.  What is wrong with `$_GET`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth i chose to go with $_GET. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
extract($_REQUEST);
```

to achieve something like this. Of course with the same security implications as for the (now removed) setting `register_globals`, so you really have to know what you do.